# NSInternalInconsistencyException Invalid parameter not satisfying: color when pushing view

Tags: ios

When i try to navigate to another screen via the navcontroller, I get an NSInternalInconsistencyException. I have totally no idea what to do with this, can anybody help me please?

*EDIT
It runs fine on the iOS 6 simulator, but on an iPad 1 4.3 gives me the crash.

This is the code snippet:

```
LoginViewController* loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginView animated:YES];
```

And the error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITextFieldLabel setTextColor:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1448.89/UILabel.m:314
2012-10-20 11:52:54.477 hra[1854:507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: color'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x331a964f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35b81c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   CoreFoundation                      0x331a9491 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 68
3   Foundation                          0x359d8573 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 62
4   UIKit                               0x32d3f991 -[UILabel setTextColor:] + 96
5   UIKit                               0x32d774df -[UITextField createTextLabelWithTextColor:] + 150
6   UIKit                               0x32e7e925 -[UITextField initWithCoder:] + 344
7   UIKit                               0x32f6d1cf UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1646
8   UIKit                               0x32f6d347 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 66
9   UIKit                               0x32f0c0bd -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 88
10  UIKit                               0x32f6d1cf UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1646
11  UIKit                               0x32f6cd99 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 568
12  UIKit                               0x32f6d347 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 66
13  UIKit                               0x32f0b7c7 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 458
14  UIKit                               0x32f0ce09 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 92
15  UIKit                               0x32e865e9 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 36
16  UIKit                               0x32e53fa5 -[UIViewController loadView] + 80
17  UIKit                               0x32d38ebf -[UIViewController view] + 30
18  UIKit                               0x32d475ef -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 22
19  UIKit                               0x32d4745f -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 30
20  UIKit                               0x32d4735d -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 24
21  UIKit                               0x32d46e35 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 380
22  UIKit                               0x32d46c43 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 182
23  UIKit                               0x32d38d5d -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 640
24  UIKit                               0x32d38ad3 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 34
25  hra                                 0x000102d9 -[MainMenuController goToLoginScreenButtonPressed:] + 156
26  CoreFoundation                      0x33119571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 24
27  UIKit                               0x32d1eec9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 84
28  UIKit                               0x32d1ee69 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
29  UIKit                               0x32d1ee3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
30  UIKit                               0x32d1eb8d -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 356
31  UIKit                               0x32d1f423 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 342
32  UIKit                               0x32d1dbf5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 368
33  UIKit                               0x32d1d56f -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 262
34  UIKit                               0x32d06313 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 298
35  UIKit                               0x32d05c53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
36  GraphicsServices                    0x35fdee77 PurpleEventCallback + 666
37  CoreFoundation                      0x33180a97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
38  CoreFoundation                      0x3318283f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
39  CoreFoundation                      0x3318360d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
40  CoreFoundation                      0x33113ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
41  CoreFoundation                      0x33113dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
42  GraphicsServices                    0x35fde41f GSEventRunModal + 114
43  GraphicsServices                    0x35fde4cb GSEventRun + 62
44  UIKit                               0x32d30d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
45  UIKit                               0x32d2e807 UIApplicationMain + 670
46  hra                                 0x00002bdb main + 158
47  hra                                 0x00002b38 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

If there is more info needed, please ask and I'll provide what I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a closer look at the xib and found out that the color for one of my textviews was set to "Black". I set it to "default" and it all worked again.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to `[UITextFieldLabel setTextColor:]` not viewcontroller. Check it your textfield color in your code.

Comment: I dont set the textcolor in the code. The xib files are all using default colors.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is occours in xcode 4.5 onwards. So please make sure that in your xib file if there is any view which is not in use then remove it. will help you guys.